# Python program to convert a text file into an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, text-files

I have a text file :

```
Created 30/01/2018 18:28 by Windographer 4.0.26

Latitude = N 9.601639
Longitude = E 98.476861
Elevation = 0 m
Calm threshold = 0 m/s

Included flags: <Unflagged data>
Excluded flags: Invalid

Time stamps indicate the beginning of the time step.

Date/Time   Ban Kong Niam [m/s] 
2008-06-01 00:00    9999
2008-06-01 01:00    9999
2008-06-01 02:00    9999
2008-06-01 03:00    9999
2008-06-01 04:00    9999
2008-06-01 05:00    9999
2008-06-01 06:00    9999
2008-06-01 07:00    9999
2008-06-01 08:00    9999
```

Now, I want to convert this text file into an Excel file.

I am able to write a python program for creating an excel file if the text file contains only the following lines :

```
Date/Time   Ban Kong Niam [m/s] 
2008-06-01 00:00    9999
2008-06-01 01:00    9999
2008-06-01 02:00    9999
2008-06-01 03:00    9999
2008-06-01 04:00    9999
2008-06-01 05:00    9999
2008-06-01 06:00    9999
2008-06-01 07:00    9999
2008-06-01 08:00    9999
```

For that, I used the python code :

```
data = []
with open("E:/Sreeraj/Thailand/1. Ban Kong Niam.txt") as f:
for line in f:
    data.append([word for word in line.split("\t") if word])
print data
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wb.add_sheet("New Sheet")
for row_index in range(len(data)):
    for col_index in range(len(data[row_index])):
        sheet.write(row_index, col_index, data[row_index][col_index])
wb.save("E:/Sreeraj/Thailand/hi.xls")
```

This python code worked perfectly.

But, I want to convert entire text file into an Excel file. For, that, I want to  print :

```
Created 30/01/2018 18:28 by Windographer 4.0.26

Latitude = N 9.601639
Longitude = E 98.476861
Elevation = 0 m
Calm threshold = 0 m/s

Included flags: <Unflagged data>
Excluded flags: Invalid

Time stamps indicate the beginning of the time step.
```

How can I make a single python program which converts the entire text file with the given below lines into an Excel file ?

```
Created 30/01/2018 18:28 by Windographer 4.0.26

Latitude = N 9.601639
Longitude = E 98.476861
Elevation = 0 m
Calm threshold = 0 m/s

Included flags: <Unflagged data>
Excluded flags: Invalid

Time stamps indicate the beginning of the time step.

Date/Time   Ban Kong Niam [m/s] 
2008-06-01 00:00    9999
2008-06-01 01:00    9999
2008-06-01 02:00    9999
2008-06-01 03:00    9999
2008-06-01 04:00    9999
2008-06-01 05:00    9999
2008-06-01 06:00    9999
2008-06-01 07:00    9999
2008-06-01 08:00    9999
```

Comment: Do you need Python at all? Excel can read a tab-delimited text file.

Comment: @asongtoruin  Yes; I must have to write a python code. And I have successfully wrote the python code for doing this task successfully. I have given the python code in the Answers section. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a single python program which will do this task successfully.

```
import xlrd
from xlwt import Workbook

data = []
head = []
mergedlist = []
path = "E:/Sreeraj/Thailand/"
file = "1. Ban Kong Niam"
text = path + file + ".txt"
excel = path + file + ".xls"


with open(text) as f:
    for cnt, line in enumerate(f):
        if cnt < 12:
            mergedlist.append(line)

with open(text) as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append([word for word in line.split("\t") if word])

mergedlist = head + data

import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wb.add_sheet("New Sheet")
for row_index in range(len(mergedlist)):
    for col_index in range(len(mergedlist[row_index])):
        sheet.write(row_index, col_index, mergedlist[row_index][col_index])


wb.save(excel)
```

Thus, using the above python program which I wrote, I can perfectly get the excel file output as given below.

```
Created 30/01/2018 18:28 by Windographer 4.0.26

Latitude = N 9.601639
Longitude = E 98.476861
Elevation = 0 m
Calm threshold = 0 m/s

Included flags: <Unflagged data>
Excluded flags: Invalid

Time stamps indicate the beginning of the time step.

Date/Time   Ban Kong Niam [m/s] 
2008-06-01 00:00    9999
2008-06-01 01:00    9999
2008-06-01 02:00    9999
2008-06-01 03:00    9999
2008-06-01 04:00    9999
2008-06-01 05:00    9999
2008-06-01 06:00    9999
2008-06-01 07:00    9999
2008-06-01 08:00    9999
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the IO-Tools of pandas to get the tabular information:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table("filename.txt", header=12, parse_dates=True) # header: row-number of your header
df.to_excel('path_to_file.xlsx', sheet_name='Tabular')
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel files accept .CSV's so you can open a text file in your IDE and write what you want in the file with respect to new lines. And between each value (either a title or piece of data) add a comma','. After you are done writing the file, copy it and paste wherever you like then change it's extension to ".CSV" then double click it and you are good to go